# Clear image on picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

How can I clear draw image on picturebox?
The following doesn't help me:

```
pictbox.Image = null;
pictbox.Invalidate();
```

Please help.

**EDIT**

```
private void pictbox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{ 
     Graphics g = e.Graphics; 
     vl.Draw(g, ref tran.realListForInsert); 
} 

public void Draw(Graphics g, ref List<double> arr) 
{ 
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3), nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstName)].pict.Location.X, nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstName)].pict.Location.Y, 25, 25); 
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Green, 3), nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstArgName)].pict.Location.X, nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstArgName)].pict.Location.Y, 25, 25); 
    nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstName)].text.Text = arr[Convert.ToInt32(templstArgName)].ToString(); 
    arr[Convert.ToInt32(templstName)] = arr[Convert.ToInt32(templstArgName)]; 
}
```

Answer (score 45):

Setting the [`Image` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx) to null will work just fine. It will clear whatever image is currently displayed in the picture box. Make sure that you've written the code exactly like this:

```
picBox.Image = null;
```

Answer (score 37):

As others have said, setting the `Image` property to `null` should work.

If it doesn't, it might mean that you used the [InitialImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.initialimage.aspx) property to display your image. If that's indeed the case, try setting that property to `null` instead:

```
pictBox.InitialImage = null;
```

Comment: From comments to another answer, it looks like this is probably the correct solution. Probably never would have come up with that, I can't imagine how this property is even remotely useful in WinForms apps.

Comment: @Cody, the `InitialImage` property holds the image that is displayed while the actual image is loading (usually through the `ImageLocation` property). You can think of it as a temporary placeholder. I agree with your comment in @V4Vendetta's answer, it doesn't look like the questioner's `PictureBox` actually contains an image, but it *does* look like he wants to remove the placeholder, which might not be possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did NOT work for me all the time.I've shown blow how I cleared the picture box.

Comment: Setting the Image to null worked for me.  We use an InitialImage of a bitmap that says "No Picture Loaded" so we can tell if there's a picture loaded, trying to load, or broken.

Answer (score 18):

```
if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.Image = null;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need the following:

```
pictbox.Image = null;
pictbox.update();
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to clear the Images drawn via PictureBox.

This you would be achieved via a Bitmap object and using Graphics object. you might be doing something like

```
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(pictbox.Image);
graphic.Clear(Color.Red) //Color to fill the background and reset the box
```

Is this what you were looking out?

**EDIT**

Since you are using the paint method this would cause it to be redrawn every time, I would suggest you to set a flag at the formlevel indicating whether it should or not paint the Picturebox

```
private bool _shouldDraw = true;
public bool ShouldDraw
{
    get { return _shouldDraw; }
    set { _shouldDraw = value; }
}
```

In your paint just use

```
if(ShouldDraw)
  //do your stuff
```

When you click the button set this property to false and you should be fine.

Comment: Uhh, you can't draw images via a PictureBox in the first place, so this doesn't make a lot of sense. You're just filling the image displayed by the picture box with the color red. If you want to *remove* the image altogether, you need to set the `Image` property to `null`, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @cody well he mentioned clearing **draw image** so i assumed he is using graphic objects to manipulate the image and performing some actions on the same.

Comment: I think the problem is in this. But display exception "ArgumentNullException was unhandled"

Comment: when i click on button which has this code you described(sorry for my english;))

Comment: The code above will produce an `ArgumentNullException` if `pictBox.Image` is not set to an image. That is, if you've set it to `null`. You can't create a `Graphics` object from `null`.

Comment: Well first are you drawing via picturebox as i assumed or you are trying the code. what is the null value being passed (i think pictbox.Image is null) Is it so ?

Comment: I also saw that pictBox.Image is always null, but pictBox.InitialImage is "{System.Drawing.Bitmap}"

Comment: @ktarik: So you need to clear the `InitialImage` property by setting it to `null`. See Frederic's answer for details.

Comment: InitialImage and ErrorImage is always seen in Designer properties as BitMap, i think this is what the OP is referring to

Comment: @ktarik: What, exactly, convinces you that there *is* an image displayed in your picture box?

Comment: @ktarik Can you post code where by you are setting the image to be displayed

Comment: private void pictbox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                      
                vl.Draw(g, ref tran.realListForInsert);
  
      }

Comment: public void Draw(Graphics g,ref List<double>arr) { g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3), nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstName)].pict.Location.X, nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstName)].pict.Location.Y, 25, 25);
                g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Green, 3), nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstArgName)].pict.Location.X, nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstArgName)].pict.Location.Y, 25, 25);
                nodeArr[Convert.ToInt32(templstName)].text.Text = arr[Convert.ToInt32(templstArgName)].ToString();
                arr[Convert.ToInt32(templstName)] = arr[Convert.ToInt32(templstArgName)];}

Comment: @cody so he is actually drawing as i suspected

Comment: What's `vl` that you're calling the `Draw` method on? This is not how you're supposed to draw things. The picture box in .NET is not a replacement for the Picture Box control in VB 6. It's not a container for your own artwork.

Answer (score 5):

```
private void ClearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Studentpicture.Image = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Sake of Understanding:

Depending on how you're approaching your objective(s), keep in mind that the developer is responsible to Dispose everything that is no longer being used or necessary.

**This means:** Everything you've created along with your pictureBox (i.e: Graphics, List; etc) shall be disposed whenever it is no longer necessary.

**For Instance:**
Let's say you have a Image File Loaded into your PictureBox, and you wish to somehow Delete that file.
If you don't unload the Image File from PictureBox correctly; you won't be able to delete the file, as this will likely throw an Exception saying that the file is being used.

**Therefore you'd be required to do something like:**

```
pic_PhotoDisplay.Image.Dispose();
pic_PhotoDisplay.Image = null;
pic_PhotoDisplay.ImageLocation = null;
// Required if you've drawn something in the PictureBox. Just Don't forget to Dispose Graphic.
pic_PhotoDisplay.Update();

// Depending on your approach; Dispose the Graphics with Something Like:
gfx = null;
gfx.Clear();
gfx.Dispose();
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a stubborn image too, that wouldn't go away 
by setting the Image and InitialImage to null.
To remove the image from the pictureBox for good, I had to use the code below,
by calling Application.DoEvents() repeatedly:

```
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (_pictureBox.Image != null)
                _pictureBox.Image.Dispose();
            _pictureBox.Image = null;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (_pictureBox.InitialImage != null)
                _pictureBox.InitialImage.Dispose();
            _pictureBox.InitialImage = null;
            _pictureBox.Update();
            Application.DoEvents();
            _pictureBox.Refresh();
```

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` is completely unnecessary here. - Plus you are running the same commands twice, whats the point?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a Refresh() statement after the Image = null to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

```
pictureBox1.Image= new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
```

Answer (score -1):

Its so simple!
You can go with your button click event,
I used it with a button property Name: "btnClearImage"

```
// Note 1a:
// after clearing the picture box 
// you can also disable clear button 
// by inserting follwoing one line of code:

btnClearImage.Enabled = false   

// Note 1b:
// you should set your button Enabled property
// to "False"
// after that you will need to Insert 
// the following line to concerned event or button
// that load your image into picturebox1 
// code line is as follows:

btnClearImage.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this method to clear the image from picturebox. It may help some one

```
private void btnClear1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            img1.ImageLocation = null;
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't clear the image, it does nothing.

Answer (score -2):

You should try. When you clear your Graphics you must choose color. SystemColors.Control is native color of form

```
Graphics g = pB.CreateGraphics();
g.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
```

Answer (score -3):

[clear pictureBox in c# winform Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeZsc.png)
Simple way to clear pictureBox in c# winform Application