# wiping of PictureBox image

Tags: .net, winforms, picturebox

Anybody who can help me point to a correct direction on samples on how to wipe PictureBox image. I was able to make it using the Animator dll but still wants to take other path if there are any.

By the way i'm using windows forms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is as easy as setting the Image property to null. see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856196/clear-image-on-picturebox) question...

Comment: Thanks @kennyzx for that idea. But making it null would hide the image immediately. The requirement it to wipe the picture, either left to right, with a certain time. Like i want to wipe it for a duration of 3 seconds. For bigger images, i will wipe it for a duration of 8 seconds.

Comment: anybody have an idea on this?

Comment: OK, you need to be specific about "wiping", define the animation behavior (If I understand your comment correctly, that is something like fading out a PPT slide from right to left). Edit your own question so it appears at the "active questions" page to draw others' attention, your comment is unheard since the question is not _active_ anymore.